# ionic app size not decreased even after reducing splash screen size

Tags: android, ionic-framework, splash-screen

Hi guys i have been working on ionic app and i have added an splash screen to it the file type was **.png** and in the beginning its size was **15 MB** and my ionic app size was **30 MB** now i have reduced the splash screen size to **1.92 MB** now my app size is **28.3 MB** so little confused and i don't know what to do to reduce the size of the **.apk** file please do let me know about any possible solution for this
Thanks in advance

Comment: delete unused plugins if it is there in plugins folder

Answer (score 1):

I mainly use [preen](https://github.com/BradDenver/Preen) and [uglify](https://github.com/rossmartin/cordova-uglify). See this answer for more information on preen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37369176/1786341

Remember to include in your index.html, only the minified versions of the libs (*.min.js, *.min.css), and to properly inject the dependencies in your controllers (see [this post](https://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification) and the [angular docs on dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)).

Some useful links:

http://blog.ionic.io/minifying-your-source-code/

https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-minify-an-ionic-application-for-production/